# pyspark substring and aggregation

Tags: substring, pyspark, aggregate

I am new to Spark and I've got a csv file with such data:

```
date,            accidents, injured
2015/20/03 18:00    15,          5
2015/20/03 18:30    25,          4
2015/20/03 21:10    14,          7
2015/20/02 21:00    15,          6
```

I would like to aggregate this data by a specific hour of when it has happened. My idea is to Substring date to 'year/month/day hh' with no minutes so I can make it a key. I wanted to give average of accidents and injured by each hour. Maybe there is a different, smarter way with pyspark?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you're going to do afterwards, I guess.

The simplest way would be to do as you suggest: substring the date string and then aggregate:

```
data = [('2015/20/03 18:00', 15, 5), 
    ('2015/20/03 18:30', 25, 4),
    ('2015/20/03 21:10', 14, 7),
    ('2015/20/02 21:00', 15, 6)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['date', 'accidents', 'injured'])

df.withColumn('date_hr',
              df['date'].substr(1, 13)
     ).groupby('date_hr')\
      .agg({'accidents': 'avg', 'injured': 'avg'})\
      .show()
```

If you, however, want to do some more computation later on, you can parse the data to a `TimestampType()` and then extract the date and hour from that.

```
import pyspark.sql.types as typ
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from datetime import datetime

parseString =  udf(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y/%d/%m %H:%M'),   typ.TimestampType())
getDate =  udf(lambda x: x.date(), typ.DateType())
getHour = udf(lambda x: int(x.hour), typ.IntegerType())

df.withColumn('date_parsed', parseString(col('date'))) \
    .withColumn('date_only', getDate(col('date_parsed'))) \
    .withColumn('hour', getHour(col('date_parsed'))) \
    .groupby('date_only', 'hour') \
    .agg({'accidents': 'avg', 'injured': 'avg'})\
    .show()
```

Comment: managed to substring when mapping quite easily using y[0][:13]. believe your solution looks more elegant. Thank you! Have one more question, if I had another file with other data let's say from a different year, how would I get an average of that accidents and injuries ? putting all in one file and then running calculations?

Comment: I'd either read that file and do the aggregation on that data only or, if necessary for you to have the results in one go (and assuming you work with Spark 2.0), you can `.union(...)` the two (or more) `DataFrames` together. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.union