# Pyspark - Convert mmddyy to YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: python, datetime, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a large file, which has one of the field in mmddyy format having string as datatype and I need to convert it into YYYY-MM-DD. I did tried creating UDF and convert referring to one of the post but its throwing error. Sample code:

Actual field in dataframe:

```
+-----------+
|DATE_OPENED|
+-----------+
|     072111|
|     090606|
```

Expected Output:

```
+---------------+
|    DATE_OPENED|
+---------------+
|     2011-07-21|
|     2006-06-09|
```

Sample Code:

```
func =  udf (lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%m%d%Y'), DateType())

newdf = olddf.withColumn('open_dt' ,date_format(func(col('DATE_OPENED')) , 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Error:

```
Error : ValueError: time data '072111' does not match format '%m%d%Y'
```

Comment: See my updated answer. It uses a more standard way of solving the problem without relying on an UDF.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve it without creating a udf , I did refer to a similar post ([pyspark substring and aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41526705/pyspark-substring-and-aggregation)) on stack and it just worked perfectly.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
format = 'mmddyy'
col = unix_timestamp(df1['DATE_OPENED'], format).cast('timestamp')
df1 = df1.withColumn("DATE_OPENED", col)

df2 = df.withColumn('open_dt', df['DATE_OPENED'].substr(1, 11))
```

Comment: You shouldn't depend on `substr`. You can use `from_unixtime` to give a format. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#from_unixtime-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without relying on a slow `UDF`. Instead, parse the data with `unix_timestamp` by specifying the correct format. Then cast the column to `DateType` which will give you the format you want by default (yyyy-mm-dd):

```
df.withColumn('DATE_OPENED', unix_timestamp('DATE_OPENED','mmddyy').cast(DateType()))
```

If you have Spark version 2.2+ there is an even more convenient method, `to_date`:

```
df.withColumn('DATE_OPENEND', to_date('DATE_OPENED','mmddyy'))
```